# How to impose a "boundary" condition inside a computing domain?

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-conditions

I need to set a "boundary" condition not at the boundaries of the computing domain but inside the domain during solving an ODE with FDM. The problem is a boundary value problem, which has been implemented based on [pdetoae](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127980/dynamic%20-%20euler%20-%20bernoulli%20-%20beam%20-%20equation/127997%20#127997) devised by @xzczd.

1. Prepare the mesh:

   ```
   L = 6; domain = {-L, L};
   points = 21;
   difforder = 4; grid = Array[# &, points, domain];
   (*please find the function from the link above*)
   ptoafunc = pdetoae[u[x], grid, difforder];
   ```
2. Discretize the system. Please note that **the last condition `u'[0] == 0` of `bc` is what I want to impose inside the domain** `[-L,L]`:

   ```
   eq = u[x] u'[x] + u''[x] + u''''[x] - 2*u'[x] == 0;
   bc = {u[-L] == 0, u[L] == 0, u'[-L] == 0, u'[L] == 0, u'[0] == 0};

   del = #[[3 ;; -3]] &;
   ae = ptoafunc@eq // del;
   aebc = ptoafunc@bc;
   ```
3. Solve the resulting system with `FindRoot`:

   ```
   ic[x_] = 10*Cos[\[Pi]/(2 L) x];
   solrule = FindRoot[{ae, aebc}, Table[{u@x, ic@x}, {x, grid}]]
   ```

Mathematica gives the following error:

> FindRoot::nveq: "The number of equations does not match the number of variables in FindRoot[...]."

I also tried to remove one or two boundary conditions among the first four of `bc`, for example, `u[-L] == 0,(*u[L] == 0,*)u'[-L] == 0,(*u'[L] == 0,*)`. However, the above error remains. Here, without the last condition `u'[0] == 0`, the code works well, but I need to additionally set this "boundary" condition to obtain a special function $u(x)$.

Thank you for any suggestion!

**Update (according to xzczd's suggestion):**
Such a b.c could be imposed with

```
midcond = ptoafunc[u'[0] == 0][[(points + 1)/2]]
```

Now we would have 5 b.c.s, and the problem appears to be ill-posed, so the code gives the same warning again. Thus, we must remove one of them. Next, using `aebc = ptoafunc@bc~Join~{midcond}` as the new b.c.s. `FindRoot` gives a reasonable solution.

Comment: Currently `pdetoae` cannot handle b.c. that's inside the domain, it'll just discretize `u'[0]==0` as if it's `u'[x]==0`, just execute `ptoafunc[u'[0]==0]` and observe. It's not hard to circumvent this, you can use `Part` to extract the needed b.c. from  `ptoafunc[u'[0]==0]`. However, are you sure these 5 b.c.s form a well-posed problem? Notice imposing b.c. inside the domain is essentially equivalent to split the original domain.

Comment: @xzczd thank you for the help. Have a quick review for my update?

Comment: Removing one b.c. at $x=\pm L$ is a possible way to avoid the warning of course. Now there's nothing wrong in the programming side, but I think one needs to check carefully to see if the result is reasonable, because the b.c. imposed in this case is a bit unusual, I should say.

Comment: There is an obvious solution `u[x]=0`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev yes, it admits the trivial solution `u=0`. However, I want to find the non-trivial ones :)

Comment: This looks like a Sturm-Liouville problem!

Comment: @CATrevillian yep, it happens to look like the Sturm-Liouville problem. Any suggestion:)